# Does CppSQLite queries the disk or cache?

Tags: sqlite, cppsqlite

I use CppSQLite 3.5.7.

Is there way to log / get information about whether the SQLite query uses the disk or cache to get the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite C API has the [sqlite3_db_status() function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_status.html), which allows querying the [SQLITE_DBSTATUS_CACHE_HIT/MISS](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbstatus_options.html) counters.

The CppSQLite library does not expose this API; you'd have to modify it.

Comment: 3.5.7 is almost ten years old. There is no good reason for having to use that, and then be concerned about performance.